# How to stop viewing before append data into it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTMl like :

```
<div id="myId">
  stack over
  some data always display before it is filled new data.
</div>
```

when i use append like :

```
$("#myId").each(function(){
//make append new data here.
}
```

My gotten issue is the old data still appear before the new data overwrite it on load.

How can I stop viewing it.

I put jQuery into under of HTML elements.

For help, please give me your jsfiddle demo (thanks)

Comment: you should prepare a your fiddle first before asking others to prepare :)

Comment: @UDB: your right. :). Problem is solved. I found a document.write command inside my code. It is may main reason lead to error. Thank all for help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="myId" style="display:none">
  stack over
  some data always display before it is filled new data.
</div>


$("#myId").show().each(function(){
//make append new data here.
}
```

Or if you want the div to still take up space, you could use visibility:hidden instead of display:none